# Office UI Fabric DocumentCard Set OverflowDocumentCount

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Is there a way to set or disable the OverflowDocumentCount of DocumentCard? Currently it is defaulted to 3 and I can't seem to change it:

[image]

I would want to display all files basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately neither via [`DocumentCardPreview` component](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/DocumentCard/DocumentCardPreview.tsx) methods nor via properties (`IDocumentCardPreviewProps`), the limit for the items in preview mode could not be modified.

But you could consider to introduce a *custom* `DocumentCardPreview` component to display all the items, for example:

```
const MyDocumentCardPreview = (props: IDocumentCardPreviewProps) => {
  const { previewImages } = props;

  const fileListItems = previewImages.map((file, fileIndex) => (
    <li key={fileIndex}>
      <Image
        className={css(
          "ms-DocumentCardPreview-fileListIcon",
          styles.fileListIcon
        )}
        src={file.iconSrc}
        role="presentation"
        alt=""
        width="16px"
        height="16px"
      />
      <Link {...file.linkProps}>{file.name}</Link>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div
      className={css(
        "ms-DocumentCardPreview",
        styles.preview,
        "is-fileList " + styles.previewIsFileList
      )}
    >
      <ul className={css("ms-DocumentCardPreview-fileList", styles.fileList)}>
        {fileListItems}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dys1hc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getOverflowDocumentCountText` prop on the `DocumentCardPreview` component to customize the overflow text.

```
<DocumentCard>
  <DocumentCardPreview
    previewImages={previewImages}
    getOverflowDocumentCountText={getOverflowDocumentCountText}
  />
</DocumentCard>
```

It takes a function, which (optionally) takes the overflow count and returns a string:

```
const getOverflowDocumentCountText = (overflowCount) => "+ 315 more";
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/24p4wok5l0) of it in action.